# Choosing different views for module base Zend application

Tags: zend-framework

I have defined modules in my application using addModuleDirectory :

```
  Application
                |
                modules
                           |
                           module1
                           |
                           module2
```

Now I want to set different views for each module in my Bootstrap.php how to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean different 'layouts'?

Comment: Yes that is right , setting different view for each module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you want is a way to switch **layout** not *views* depending on the module, what you need is a standard [front controller plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html).

A really simple implementation would be:

```
class LayoutModuleSwitcher extends \Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    /**
     * @param Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract Request object
     */
    public function routeShutdown(\Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        \Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()
            ->setLayoutPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts/' . $request->getModuleName() . '/scripts/');
    }
}
```

While having the following layouts structure:

```
application/layouts/module1/scripts/layout.phtml
application/layouts/module2/scripts/layout.phtml
```

Depending on the following configuration:

```
resources.frontController.plugins.LayoutModuleSwitcher = "Ahp\Controller\Plugin\LayoutModuleSwitcher"
resources.layout.layout = "layout"; The name of your layout.phtml without the suffix, needed to init layout
```